# Trouble with slider arrows

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, frontend

I have a lot of trouble with my slider arrows as I am following along with a tutorial on youtube. Instead of going next to the picture and testimonial, it goes on the top. It didn't happen this way at first, but then I had a problem with glider.js, so I rewrote the code, and then the flaw appeared

**HTML Code**

```
    <section class="testimonials-section">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Testimonials</h2>

        <div class="testimonials container">
          <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="slide-container">
                <div class="content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Fuga, dolorem? Soluta aperiam maxime nam ducimus ab fuga. 
                    Libero, consequatur placeat! Explicabo aut labore enim? Tenetur, esse a. 
                    Quidem, deleniti provident.
                  </p>
                  <div class="name">
                    <strong>Darlene Richards,</strong> Amazon
                  </div>
                </div>

                <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="slide-container">
                <div class="content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Fuga, dolorem? Soluta aperiam maxime nam ducimus ab fuga. 
                    Libero, consequatur placeat! Explicabo aut labore enim? Tenetur, esse a. 
                    Quidem, deleniti provident.
                  </p>
                  <div class="name">
                    <strong>Peter Williams,</strong> Louis Vuitton
                  </div>
                </div>

                <img src="images/testimonial3.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="slide-container">
                <div class="content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Fuga, dolorem? Soluta aperiam maxime nam ducimus ab fuga. 
                    Libero, consequatur placeat! Explicabo aut labore enim? Tenetur, esse a. 
                    Quidem, deleniti provident.
                  </p>
                  <div class="name">
                    <strong>Tara Green,</strong> Ferrari
                  </div>
                </div>

                <img src="images/testimonial2.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <span class="slider-prev">
            <img src="images/left-arrow.svg" alt="">
          </span>

          <span class="slider-next">
            <img src="images/right-arrow.svg" alt="">
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.slider-prev,
.slider-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-next {
    right: 0;
}
```

[image: Where the slider arrows end up]
[image: Where the slider arrows are supposed to go]

Comment: This is happening because of the "position: absolute" on the sliders. Try adding a "position: relative" to the "testimonial" div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of how the css position property works [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Try add this line and see if it helps:

**edit** use `.testimonials.container` selector not `.testimonials`

```css
.testimonials.container  {
  position: relative;
}
```